# Ionic 5 capacitor adMob issue

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

I am trying to integrate adMob using capacitor to my ionic app. I followed these steps https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free

When I run the solution on Android Studio I am getting this error.

```
C:\Projects\my-app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I also tried admob free and encountered a few errors. I tried this later <https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob>  If you can't find a solution, you can try this.